# Appendix without letter in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, appendices

I am a newbie in Latex. My goal is to have the word "Chapter" in the title of any chapter, and the word "Appendix" in the title of appendix. I also want to add "Appendix" in TOC. However, using the following MWE from my university, I end up having "Appendix A" in TOC. How can I remove the letter "A" in TOC.

```
\documentclass[12]{thesis}

\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\newcommand{\spacemultiplier}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\spacemultiplier}\normalsize

\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{
%TABLE OF CONTENTS
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
}
\newpage
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\LARGE\sc\fillast}{Chapter
  \thechapter}{0pt}{}[\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\spacemultiplier}\normalsize]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1.4cm}{20pt}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
}

% Appendix setup
\newcommand{\universityappendix}{
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
\LARGE\sc\fillast}{Appendix}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{blah blah}
This is a chapter

\universityappendix
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{blah blah}
this is appendix
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Changing the appendix to

```
\universityappendix
\begin{appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{-1ex}. blah blah}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter{blah blah}
this is appendix
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

does not modify the appendix itself, but changes the TOC to[image: picture of TOC]

The first added line produces the TOC entry; the second added line suppresses the one that was already there.
You might want to fiddle slightly with the `-1ex`, which I think is a bit long.